# Add Devise Gem to new Rails project creates test users errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I haven't used Devise before. My site is nothing but bootstrap, HTML, styles and some static pages at this point. I am [using this Gemfile](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/user_microposts#code-final_gemfile) All my tests passed until I ran `rake db:migrate`. I ran these steps in this order.

- add `gem 'devise'`, run `bundle install`. (tests green)
- run `rails generate devise:install`, add flash notices (tests green)
- add action_mailer defaults line to development, test and production env per Docs (tests green)
- run `rails generate devise user` (tests wont run due to pending migrations)
- Checked the new model per docs but made no changes to defaults.
- run `rails db:migrate` (tests red) **running this created a test.sqlite3 file in my db folder**

I'm now getting this error:

`ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique:         ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2017-01-01 22:14:19.589023', '2017-01-01 22:14:19.589023', 298486374)`

on all of my tests. Which is weird since I haven't created any tests that do anything besides check if HTML elements exist and links work but nonetheless...

It seems in order to pass the uniquiness constraint I need a user but I haven't created any. It also has something to do with SQLite. How can I get this test to pass, with Devise at my current point. I'm using the Hartl tutorial as a guide basically. I do recall there is a step where we create fake users but this isn't the purpose of that moment?

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @title = "FFP"
  end

  test "should get root" do
    get root_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", @title
  end
end
```

Here is my Schema currently.

```
 ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170101224251) do

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

Comment: It sounds like you already have two values in the user.email field that are duplicates, delete one of the offending values and try again.

Comment: This error will occur when you are either trying to add a unique constraint to an existing column that already has duplicated values, or if you are trying to insert a value into a field that already has that value.

Comment: Devise add the uniqueness for the user.email. And I think somewhere you try to create an User without email address.

Comment: @JeffDavenport  Thanks for your replies. I added my current Schema file to my question for clarity. I don't see a place where I'm having a column conflict. I think that my test is trying to create a user for some reason but I don't see where. There was no User model until I generated it with Devise

Comment: @tomtomtom I agree that appears to be the issue. Should I update my `test/models/user_test.rb` somehow? Possibly use the `test/fixtures/users.yml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this problem by updating your `test/fixtures/users.yml` file in the following manner.

```
one:
  email: "mail@mail.com"
#
two:
  email: "mail_2@mail.com"
```